# textarea inside div: why there is an extra 1px line?

Tags: css, html, textarea

Why the height of the `div` in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/7bJSp/17/) is 101 rather than 100 ?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
Div height: <span id="wrapper_height"></span>
<br />
Textarea height: <span id="textarea_height"></span>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
}
textarea {
    border: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #777;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrapper_height').html($('div').height());
    $('#textarea_height').html($('textarea').height());
});
```

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle for your work: http://jsfiddle.net/MwFwB/

Comment: it gives me height 105 in Chrome...however, Chrome also has that "auto resize" thing for textareas which may well be confusing things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the TEXTAREA element is inline-level by default. This means that there is additional vertical space between the baseline and the descender:

http://vidasp.net/media/CSS-vertical-align.gif

To get rid of that vertical space, set the TEXTAREA element to be `display:block`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7bJSp/21/

Comment: Do you familiar with a tool where one could see all these details ? (I didn't find them in Firebug)

Comment: I mean all the details in the picture above, i.e. I would like to choose a line on a page and see (maybe zoomed) where is the "baseline", "descender", e.t.c. I would like to see a picture similar to the one above.

Comment: @Misha Sorry, I don't know of such a tool.

Comment: Thanks! I was very very confused by a terrible vertical scrollbar that that appeared in a <div> with a <textarea> inside, but getting rid of the descender space, by specifying `display:block`, solved the problem :-)